# cassandra c# datastax client insert blob

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-cli

hi I wonder if there is a more elegant way of inserting blob instead of converting the byte array into string like:

```
string strblob = "0x00" + BitConverter.ToString(stream2.GetBuffer()).Replace("-", "");

ISession session = cluster.Connect("abc");

session.Execute(string.Format("insert into events(blob) values ({0})", blobStr));
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, converting the binary data to hex string format and prefixing  "0x" is the only way to load binary data into Cassandra using Datastax.

Comment: thanks Jaco. it seems a lot of memory waste... /:

Comment: also when retrieving data need to takeoff the 0x... //:

Comment: Similar question that might help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072373/insert-image-into-cassandra-blob-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more elegant and more effective solution which is to use bound statement.

```
byte[] blob = stream2.GetBuffer();
ISession session = cluster.Connect("abc");

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.Prepare("INSERT INTO events(blob) VALUES (?)");
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.Bind(blob);

session.Execute(boundStatement);
```

The idea behind PreparedStatement is to parsed the string query once and reuse it as much as you need with different values. So keep track of your prepared statements.